# Removing the comma from the last element in the string of array

Tags: java

Any suggestions for removing the comma in last element of the array when it prints?

```
public static void printList(String[] words, int count) {
    for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
        System.out.print(words[i] + ",");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I like to handle this problem is to conditionally *prepend* a comma only for the second word onwards:

```
public static void printList(String[] words, int count) {
    for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
        if (i > 0) System.out.print(",");
        System.out.print(words[i]);
    }
}
```

You could also build the output string you want, and then trim off the final comma:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
    sb.append(words[i]).append(",");
}
String output = sb.toString().replaceAll(",$", "");
System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

One quick approach:

```
public static void printList(String[] words, int count) {
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        System.out.print(words[i]);
        if(i != count-1) System.out.print(",");
    }
}
```